# How do I control the behaviour of my checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I'm looping through an array of `vehicleTypes` and show a dropdown of checkboxes. I'm using `FormControlLabel` and `<Checkbox/>` as the control. The problem is when I select a checkbox, it closes my drop down (i'm using  `<Collapse in={openModule} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>` for this.

I don't know why this is happening and it's sort of screwing up the flow of the form. I also need to tell it that when `All Vehicles` is selected, make all of the others **blacked out**

Image and code attached:

**The Code**

```
<TableCell
                                    colSpan={4}
                                    className={styles.vehicleTypeTableCell
                                    }>
                                    <Collapse in={openModule} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                                      <Table>
                                        <TableBody>
                                          {vehicleTypes.map((selection) => (
                                            <TableRow>
                                              <TableCell
                                                className={styles.vehicleTypeList}
                                                colSpan={2}
                                              >
                                                <FormControlLabel
                                                  style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }}
                                                  control={<Checkbox 
                                                  />}
                                                  label={selection}
                                                  name="names"
                                                  value={selection}
                                                  onChange={(event) => {
                                                    if (selection === 'All Vehicles') {
                                                      setSelectionDisabled(!selectionDisabled);
                                                    }
                                                    handleChange(event);
                                                  }}
                                                  disabled={
                                                    selection !== 'All Vehicles'
                                                      ? selectionDisabled
                                                      : false
                                                  }
                                                />
                                              </TableCell>
                                            </TableRow>
                                          ))}
                                        </TableBody>
                                      </Table>
                                    </Collapse>
                                  </TableCell>
```

Does anyone know how to stop this from happening?

**Video of Behavior**

[Gif of the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRAxj.gif)

Handle Change is changing the `formik` value. So, what it's doing is it's targeting names in the list below... and it's updating the value to the radio button (created by looping through the array) that is selected

```
  const initialValues = {
    brandId,
    languageCode,
    reservationType,
    purchaseDate: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    zipCode: '',
    email: '',
    confirmEmail: '',
    city: '',
    ownershipType: '',
    offerType: '',
    names: [],
    vehiclesOfInterest: [],
  };
```

Comment: What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: The expected behaviour is that when `All Vehicles` is selected all of the others grey out, and the dropdown stays open when I click any of the checkboxes. Then if I toggle it open or closed.... the state remains... ie, what I clicked before is still there

Comment: What is `handleChange` doing? I mean can you post the definition of it

Comment: I just updated it, it's a formik function just to update the value in initial values, and it does work for the `formControlLabel` but the checkbox itself seems to have a mind of its own

Answer (score 0):

https://mui.com/api/form-control-label/

You are missing `checked` property for FormControlLabel to make your selection persist

Comment: So I added this in:  `checked={ values.names && selection === values.names ? true : false }`  but unfortunately, the behavior persists. It still autocloses the second I click one of the checkboxes, and it still doesn't persist

Comment: Actually, I was able to get the checkboxes working. Had to change to this, ` checked={values.names.length > 0 && values.names.indexOf(selection)> -1 ?  true : false  }` However, the problem of the `<Collapse>` closing automatically is still there.... which I don't get at all.. How is it even controlling that.

Comment: For that can you share the whole code of it as I see it is only containing the checkboxes